# How to extract one file from Zipped file

Tags: c#, .net, unzip, zip

The scenario is that my data file is located in remote machine, the file is a zip file and its size is very big. Now I want to extract a target file according to the file name, but I don't want to download the whole file from the remote machine. Could any method help to identify the target file quickly and then download part of the data from the remote file? Btw, the development language is C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151583/c-sharp-access-text-file-in-zip-archive
Check this link

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for local code to unzip a remote file without completely downloading it. If you want to minimize the amount of data transferred, you need some service running on the remote machine doing the extraction part and then transferring only your desired file.

Comment: After searching current online solution, yeah, I don't find one support this. Then I spend time to implement it. Now I could extract any file casually!